# What will be the behaviour of superconductors if they are used as core or coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, superconductors

Superconductors are strong diamagnetic in nature so if they are used as core of any coil do magnetic lines of forces pass through them – I mean inside them just as with a soft iron core?

Secondly if they are used as the coil wound on core then change in magnetic field induces current inside them. Does mutual inductance occur in them or not – because the magnetic lines of forces don't pass through them, or because they bend towards them?

Answer (score 2):

As superconductors are perfectly diamagnetic, I would describe putting them in a transformer core as *misuse*, rather than *use*. They will do exactly what you don't want in a core material. Soft iron allows many times more flux for any given field than air, a superconductor allows zero flux, regardless of the field.

Superconducting windings, coils, behave just like ordinary windings, as far as having voltages induced on them due to changing magnetic flux linkage, and generating a field due to current flow through them, but without the \$I^2R\$ heat.

Comment: Sir i dont get this superconductors dont allow magnetic flux to pass through them so how they get magnetic induction.

Comment: @K132362SyedTahaAhmed They don't allow flux to pass through the superconductor, but if you make them into a coil, you can pass flux through the core, because the core isn't superconductor, it's just air or iron.

Comment: Actually i am wondering that copper is di-magnetic  so how does it links flux with iron core as di-magnetic material don't allow flux to pass through so how change in flux induces emf.

Comment: @K132362SyedTahaAhmed copper is slightly diamagnetic, it's very slightly repelled by a magnet, certainly not excluding flux the way a superconductor does. This is irrelevant to flux linkage, whereby a winding which *encloses* a region of space where there's flux, whether that winding is copper or superconductor, links with that flux simply by enclosing it. The flux doesn't need to penetrate the conductor material.